# jstree dnd access created element

Tags: jstree, jstree-dnd

jstree version 3.1.1, plugin dnd.

I need to drag nodes in one jstree element and drop them to another jstree element. This is working fine and i get all information about the element which is dragged, but I don't get any information about the dropped (newly) created node in the second jstree element.

dnd_stop.vakata seems not to contain this information (at least i can't find it), create_node.jstree isn't triggered, when dnd creates a new node, so i wonder how to get the id of the new node.

Please check this one: http://jsfiddle.net/amug08ms/

```
all needed code is in the example ...
```

When you drag a node from the upper jstree to the lower jstree, all information about that node is lost, except the text of the node. So how can i add the information i need to the dropped (created) node in the lower jstree node?

Thanks for any hint in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The event that is triggered when using multi-tree drag'n'drop is `copy_node.jstree`.

Here is how you can transfer the ID (using this example it should be easy to copy any other properties you may need - by default IDs and data is not copied):

```
$('#destTree').on('copy_node.jstree', function (e, data) {
    data.instance.set_id(data.node, data.original.id);
    for(var i = 0, j = data.node.children_id; i < j; i++) {
        data.instance.set_id(data.node.children_d[i], data.original.children_d[i]);
    }
});
```

Here is the updated fiddle:
http://jsfiddle.net/amug08ms/1/